# A manifold admits a non-vanishing top form iff it has an oriented atlas. Do we need connectedness here?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I appreciate anyone who can provide help.

This is a theorem in sec. 20.4 of Loring Tu's book "An introduction to manifolds"

The theorem is the following,

A manifold admits a non-vanishing top form iff it has an oriented atlas.

I manage to show one direction. The part that confuses me is that if we assume the top form, we want to show there is an oriented atlas.

Say we have a top form $\omega$, then pick a chart $(U,x)$, we know that $$\omega=fdx^1\wedge...\wedge dx^n$$ on the coordinate open set $U$. But then the book say either $f>0$ or $f<0$. I cannot see why this is the case without connectedness assumed.

Comment: WLOG, we can always take a chart at a given point to have $U$ connected.

Comment: If you are confused, just argue one connected component at a time: A manifold is orientable if and only if each connected component is.

Comment: I appreciate all the comments here. I think I get it.

Comment: You can choose an atlas where all domains of chart are connected.

Answer (score 8):

There is a preliminary step to the proof: *We may assume* that the manifold is connected.

In other words:

> The theorem for connected manifolds implies the theorem for arbitrary manifolds.

To prove this implication, suppose we already know that the theorem is true for all connected manifolds, and let $M$ be any oriented manifold. Write its component decomposition as $M = \sqcup_i M_i$. Apply the theorem to each component $M_i$ to get a nonvanishing top form $\omega_i$. We obtain a nonvanishing top form $\omega$ on $M$, whose restriction to $M_i$ is $\omega_i$, which proves the theorem for arbitrary manifolds.

Comment: This helps a lot. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

The local representation $\omega=fdx^1\wedge...\wedge dx^n$ does not allow to conclude that either $f > 0$ or $f < 0$. This is valid only if $U$ *is connected* (but it has nothing to do with the connectedness of $M$). Thus it necessary to consider only charts with a connected $U$.